# What is the average energy speed on mainstream energy cables?

Tags: energy, electricity, electrons

I've witnessed a cable rupture some time ago where it took 1-2 seconds for the energy of the apartment complex (100 metres away) to fall down.

Given the fact that theoretically (as far as I know) energy/electricity speed should be close to the velocity of ***c***, why does it took that time for the apartment complex to stop receiving the electricity?

Also, if its true that the electricity speed is close for that of ***c***, would it be feasible to export energy from wind farms to, say, a country from other continent (far, far away)?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more details about the "cable rupture" and the system, it's difficult to talk about what you saw.  It's possible the cable failure took some time.  Perhaps for a second or two arcing allowed power to continue past the break.  Perhaps there was a substation with a lot of capacitance between the break and the complex.

But yes, power flow does propagate at a significant fraction of $c$ through cables.

> if its true that the electricity speed is close for that of c, would
>   it be feasible to export energy from wind farms to, say, a country
>   from other continent (far, far away)?

The drawback to long distance energy distribution is not the speed of the transfer, but cost of building the infrastructure and the cost due to energy loss in the cables.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that there is a significant delay in the AC circuit due to inductance or capacitance.

As for power transmission, currently the longest power transmission line is about 2400 km (http://www.power-technology.com/features/featurethe-worlds-longest-power-transmission-lines-4167964/). The length of the power transmission lines is limited by losses and costs, not the speed of light:-).